# Unable to run Blender on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to run blender on Ubuntu 19.10, but I receive the following error:

> a graphics card and driver with support for opengl 3.3 or higher is required

So I tried `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"` and this is the output:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

The point is that using Ubuntu 18.04 I didn't have any problem.

Comment: You are running the latest MESA but your video card can only support up to openGL 2.1.
Can you confirm your video card?
Have you also seen
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/06/install-mesa-18-1-1-ppa-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 3):

You probably can run it without acceleration by using this command in Blender's directory:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./blender
```

Comment: It worked for me. Now can can run blender in my older system too. Thank you very much.